# google api java client not passing parameter with value 0 when using proguard-android-optimize.txt

Tags: android, proguard, android-proguard, google-api-java-client

I have a `Google API` java client model class as:

```
public final class AccountProviders extends com.google.api.client.json.GenericJson
```

with a parameter `lastSyncTime` as :

```
  /**
   * @return value or {@code null} for none
   */
  public java.lang.Long getLastSyncTime() {
    return lastSyncTime;
  }
```

while using proguard configuration :

```
release {
    resValue "string", "app_name", "MyApp"
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
}
```

things are working fine for `0` or any other `long` value as the value of `lastSyncTime` however if using following proguard configuration:

```
release {
    resValue "string", "app_name", "MyApp"
    minifyEnabled true
    shrinkResources false
    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
}
```

the API throws `503`, as param `lastSyncTime` is missing from the request, for value `0`; it is working fine for other `long` values.

**Using optimized `proguard config` is stripping the `param` of google API java client request; if the value of param is `0`**

Please suggest any remedy for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we found was that proguard replaces all instances of `new Long(0)` with same reference. (same for String/Int etc) So in this case if you have any parameter with 0 value. It would get converted to same reference of `new Long(0)`. Due to this check at `isNull` in `com.google.api.client.util.Data.java` resulting in that field being set to null. And hence it would not be passed in your API calls.

Solution : 
add following line to proguard rules to disable this proguard simplification.

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/*
```

Answer (score 1):

As Aalap found out, the Google API code creates marker instances of some types (e.g. new Boolean(true)). You can avoid the optimizations that break such code (e.g. Boolean.TRUE) with

```
-optimizations !code/simplification/object
```

or for a more local solution, just preserve this code:

```
-keepclassmembers,includecode class com.google.api.client.util.Data {
    void <clinit>();
}
```